# Lower bounding $|f'(0)|$ for holomorphic $f: \mathbb{D} \to \mathbb{D}$ when $f(0)=0$ and $f(\frac{1}{2})=c>\frac{1}{4}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\mathcal{F}_c = \{ f: \mathbb{D} \to \mathbb{D} \text{ holomorphic } | f(0)=0, f(\frac{1}{2})=c \}$ for $c\in [0, \frac{1}{2})$. Denote $m_c = \inf_{f \in \mathcal{F}_c } |f'(0)|$.

Prove

$$
\begin{align}
m_c=0& \text{ if } c \leq \frac{1}{4} \\
m_c>0& \text{ if } c > \frac{1}{4} \\
\end{align}
$$

**My try:**

I managed to show the first one by considering the function $f(z)=4cz^2$. But I'm stuck with the second one. I've tried to calculate

$$
c = f(\frac{1}{2}) - f(0)
= \int_{[0,\frac{1}{2}]} f'(z) dz
= \int_{[0,\frac{1}{2}]} \left( \int_{[0,z]}f''(w)dw + f'(0) \right) dz
= \int_{[0,\frac{1}{2}]} \int_{[0,z]}f''(w)dwdz + \frac{1}{2}f'(0)
$$

I've then tried to bound $f''(w)$ (for $w\in [0, z] \subset [0, \frac{1}{2}]$) with Cauchy formula (using countour $\gamma_r$ which is a circle of radius $r < 1 - |w|$ centered at $w$)

$$
|f''(w)| = \left| \frac{2!}{2\pi i} \int_{\gamma_r} \frac{f(s)}{(s-w)^3} ds \right|
\leq \frac{2}{2\pi} \int_{\gamma_r} \frac{|f(s)|}{|s-w|^3} |ds|
\leq \frac{2}{2\pi r^2} \int_0^{2\pi} |w+re^{it}|dt
$$

Here I used Schwarz's lemma $|f(s)| \leq |s|$.  We could use $|f| < 1$ but that doesn't give enough. But then I can't.

---

**Another approach:** Use circle centered at origin and let the radius approach $1$. Then

$$
|f''(w)| \leq \frac{2}{(1-|w|)^3} 
$$

and we have $\left|\int_{[0,\frac{1}{2}]} \int_{[0,z]}f''(w)dwdz \right| \leq \frac{1}{2}$ so

$$
c \leq  \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}|f'(0)|
$$

But this isn't enough either. We would need $\left|\int_{[0,\frac{1}{2}]} \int_{[0,z]}f''(w)dwdz \right| \leq \frac{1}{4}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $a = f'(0)$. The function $g(z) = f(z)/z$ has a removable singularity at the origin. We have $|g(z)| \le 1$ for all $z \in \Bbb D$ because of the Schwarz lemma, also $g(0) = f'(0) = a$ and $g(1/2) = 2 c$.

The [Schwarz-Pick theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma#Schwarz%E2%80%93Pick_theorem) applied to the function $g$ at $z_1 = 1/2$ and $z_2 = 0$ gives
$$
\left| \frac{2c - a}{1-2ca}\right| \le \frac 12
$$
and it follows that
$$
 2c - |a| \le |2c-a| \le \frac 12 |1-2ca| \le \frac 12 + c |a| \\
\implies 2c - \frac 12 \le (c+1)|a| \\
\implies |a| \ge \frac{4c-1}{2(c+1)} \, .
$$
This proves that
$$
m_c = \inf_{f \in \mathcal{F}_c } |f'(0)| \ge \frac{4c-1}{2(c+1)} > 0
$$
for $c > 1/4$.

Answer (score 1):

note that $f(z)=zg(z)$ with $|g| \le 1$ and $f'(0)=g(0)$. If $g(0)=0$ it follows that $f(z)=z^2h(z), |h| \le 1$ so $|f(1/2)|=|h(1/2)|/4 \le 1/4$ so $f'(0) \ne 0$ for every $f\in \mathcal{F}_c$ when $c >1/4$ fixed.

But now $\mathcal{F}_c$ is a compact set in the topology of locally uniform convergence by Montel theorem, so the set $f'(0), f\in \mathcal{F}_c$ is compact hence since it doesn't contain zero, it has a positive distance $m_c$ from zero (or if you prefer if there were $f_n \in \mathcal{F}_c, f_n'(0) \to 0$ one could choose a locally uniform convergent subsequence and the limit $f$ is in $\mathcal{F}_c$ with $f'(0)=0$ contradicting the first paragraph)